# why when I run in the haskell compiler it just says there is an error in parse input "if"

Tags: haskell

The question says i need am required to count number of digits in a list of characters and will return the Int of number of digit in the list. I may use isDigit and i need to do it with recursion

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta [] = []
counta (x:xs) = let i = 0
                if isDigit(x) then i = i + 1
                counta xs
                else counta xs
```

it shows parse error in input "if"

Comment: If you use a `let` without an `in`, then it only makes sense in a `do` block (but you here have a non-monadic type, so you can not use a `do` block). You should use `let .. in`. Note that you can not use `i = i + 1` here.

Comment: so what should I do to increase 1?

Comment: you don't. Haskell is a declarative language, so that means that *all* variable are immutable. You should think of it like: I have the count of the tail (`count xs`) what should I return for `counta (x:xs)`.

Comment: i still dont quite get it sorry about that im weak at haskell. why do i need tail( count xs) or is it tail(counta xs)?

Comment: He's not referring to the function `tail`; `xs` is already the tail of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` itself is an expression; it produces a 0 or 1 that you then add to the return value of the recursive call. You don't need a variable.

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta [] = 0
counta (x:xs) = (if isDigit x then 1 else 0) + counta xs
```

You can shorten this by taking advantage of the `Enum` instance defined for `Bool`, which converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`.

```
counta (x:xs) = fromEnum (isDigit x) + counta xs
```

---

A proper way to use a `let` statement that defines `i` would be

```
counta (x:xs) = let i = if isDigit x then 1 else 0
                in i + counta xs
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback it really do help me alot

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code

- `counta [] = []` returns a list but you have declared `counta :: [Char]->Int` which indicates it should return a Int
- you don't need parentheses for applying function, you should write `isDigit x` instead of `isDigit(x)`
- As Willem already pointed out you can't use `let` without `in` outside a `do` block, Also you can't mutate variables

Comment: so what should i do to increase 1 ? how should I increase 1 when isDigit?

Comment: Try to come up with a recursive solution for the problem before writing any code, after that it should be easy to implement.

Comment: I have the idea of checking whether is its digit from a list of char using isDigit for the head of the list. if the head isDigit, then i replace into x : counta (xs). This is my idea. Isnt it correct?

Comment: And since i cant mutate variables how do i do it?

Comment: you don't need to use head explicitly , `x` is head and `xs` is tail in your function. You can't mutate values but you can return new values, for example `f x = x + 1` takes a number returns a new number without mutating input.

Comment: If you weak in haskell as you said, I would recommend http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters you should be able to solve this problem after reading the first chapter itself